# How XMLHttpRequest is handled at javascript runtime?

Tags: javascript, c++, xmlhttprequest, browser, chromium

I am very curious about how **XMLHttpRequests** are handled at **JS runtime** level. Does it create thread per request or any other way it handles the async behaviour? If threaded manner, can someone point out in the **[chromium source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/xmlhttprequest/XMLHttpRequest.cpp&rcl=1417852722&l=927)** where exactly that is happening? So far I have found the **[XMLHttpRequest source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/xmlhttprequest/XMLHttpRequest.cpp&rcl=1417852722&l=927)** given below. But I don't find any reference of creating a thread. I would be grateful if some one can help me understand it.

Note: I am not concerned about Event loops here. Even before reaching event loop how things happen at JS runtime is what I am concerned about.